# Yii2 basic template Login logic doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, model-view-controller, yii2

I'm a newbie Yii2 developer. I've started to create my own website based on Basic Yii2 template. And after creating registration and authorization logic I ran into some issues.

1. I create new user. It's added to User table into my db right as it should.
2. I go to login page and Log in with all needed information. It works too.
3. But when it log me in it redirects me with `$this->goHome()` method. By default it's `actionIndex` in my `SiteController` and this page is still denied by rules.

My DB scheme is:

```
$this->createTable('user', [
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'username' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'email' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'password_hash' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'role' => Schema::TYPE_SMALLINT . ' NOT NULL',
    ]);
```

I set my identity class:

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
]
```

My User class extends ActiveRecord and implements IdentityInterface.

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    self::find()
        ->select('*')
        ->where(['id' => $id])
        ->one();
}
```

`SiteController` behavior method:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?']
                ]
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                echo 'DENIED ACTION: ' . $action->actionMethod;
                echo ' IS GUEST: ' . Yii::$app->user->isGuest;
                echo ' SESSION IS: ' . Yii::$app->user->enableSession;
            }
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

As you can see I've done some var_dumps in my `denyCallback` function. After I'm logged in it says:

```
IS DENIED: actionIndex IS GUEST: 1 SESSION IS: 1
```

- "Why is isGuest attribute set to 1 even when I'm logged in as user?
- "How can I fix my access logic?

Also here's some logs:
After login i have: `SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "username"='Test'`
After redirect with `goHome()`: `SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "id"=1`

And in session there's an Id: `__id 1`
Finally if I change my guests' rule to :

```
[
    'actions' => ['login', 'index'],
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => ['?']
]
```

it shows me the page I need

Let me know if I should provide more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not yii2 advanced template?

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad I'm using basic because I don't need backend and frontend division

Comment: visit [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYOcEVlv9l0)